# How to setState() on a ModalRoute?

Tags: text, flutter, dart, refresh, navigator

I write an app in flutter. I want to change the state of a string variable. After I set the state of the string variable, the ModalRoute PopUpMenu does not show the changed variable. If I close the ModalRoute PopUpMenu and open it again, I can see the changed variable.

I tried to pop the context, but I want the change on the PopUpMenu. I've got my own Overlay widget.

```dart
    class MyOverlay extends ModalRoute {
    ...
    }

    // this is my main.dart: 

    List<String> categories = ['please', 'help', 'me'];
    String _selectedCategory = 'category';

    // this is where the PopUpMenu starts
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            child: ...,
            onPressed: () {
              _showPopup(context, _popupBody(), 'Add');
            },
    ),

    _showPopup(BuildContext context, Widget widget, String title, {BuildContext popupContext}) {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MyOverlay(
               ...
                  onPressed: () {
                    try {
                      Navigator.pop(context); //close the popup
                    } catch (e) {
                      print(e);
                    }
                  },
              ...
            body: widget,
       ) ...
      );
    }

    Widget _popupBody() {
        ...
        PopupMenuButton<String>(
                  // HERE IS THE PROBLEM THIS SHOULD CHANGE WHEN I SELECT 
                  child: Text('$_selectedCategory'),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return categories.map((String choice) {
                      return PopupMenuItem<String>(
                        value: choice,
                        child: Text(choice),
                      );
                    }).toList();
                  },
                  onSelected: _selectCategory,
                ),

       ...
    }

    void _selectCategory(String category) {
        setState(() => this._selectedCategory = category);
    }
```

The text widget does not change if I select the PopupMenuItem.

Comment: im also facing same issue .. could u found the solution?

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem, I fixed for the moment using changedExternalState (); to force a rebuild, but i think maybe this isn't optimal.

Example:

```
CheckboxListTile(
              value: _checkboxValue,
              title: Text(phone),
              onChanged: (value){
                _checkboxValue = value;
                //Fix
                changedExternalState();
              },
            )
```

Comment: Oh, never saw the changedExternalState method. Looks like a hacker solution, great!

Comment: how to use this method ?

Comment: @I_User - I wanted a Button to update on my ModalRoute. I made that Button a stateful widget, with a bool in the constructor .. I then pass the bool that gets updated in the ModalRoute into that Button and when the bool is changed I am calling setState with the new value and then "changedExternalState();" - like in the example above